# how to generate header stamp rpi-pico

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the micro-ros rpi pico, how I can generate the time information for odom_msg.header.stamp. I try to use method in micro-ros ping-pong example but the clock_gettime function is not available in rpi-pico lib.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381123/how-to-generate-header-stamp-rpi-pico/) by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2021-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Pablogs thanks for the answer it now working, This my implementation code for others ref.

```
struct timespec ts;

extern int clock_gettime(clockid_t unused, struct timespec *tp);

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

odom_msg.header.stamp.sec = ts.tv_sec;

odom_msg.header.stamp.nanosec = ts.tv_nsec;
```

---

Originally posted by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) with karma: 76 on 2021-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0